# Django Rest Framework get serializer of different model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a method in one of my viewsets:

Endpoint: `/api/game/{id}/sessions`:

```
from .serializers import GameSerializer
from .models import Game
from gamesessions.models import GameSession
from gamesessions.serializers import GameSessionSerializer
from gamesessions.viewsets import GameSessionViewSet

@action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
def sessions(self, request, **id):
    game = self.get_object()
    sessions = []
    for session in GameSession.objects.filter(game=game.id):
        sessions.append(session)

    serializer = GameSessionViewSet.get_serializer(sessions, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But I'm getting an error because I can't figure out where the `get_serializer` method comes from and/or how to implement it externally.

I need to get the serializer of the session model.  I can generate the list of sessions just fine, but it says the object is not JSON serializable, which is what DRF is supposed to handle.

So I just need to know what do I import to get the seralizer from the other class?

Comment: Can you add the ***complete view class***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try, to use the serializer directly with the name like this:

```
serializer = GameSessionSerializer(sessions, many=True)
```